# Docker cannot read Serial device

Tags: python, docker, pyserial, tty

I've got the following Python code running in a docker image:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1', 19200)
while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    print(line, flush=True)
```

I've used the following command line to start the container:

```
docker run -it --device /dev/ttyS1:/dev/ttyS1 my-image:latest
```

On the host device, when I send data to the serial RX port, I can see it with the `socat` command.
While on the docker instance, I don't get any data nor print. Baudrates are the same on emitter and receiver.

My serial device is permanently attached to the host.

Is there a kind of rights to enable Serial port on Docker ? I've got no error showing up.
I'd like to avoid the use of the `privileged` flag.

Comment: There is two different devices. One is sending data to Serial, the other (docker) is receiving. Host is the device which hosts the docker instance.

Comment: If you are running Docker on Windows, you may be running into the issue in this Docker forum thread, and the linked GitHub issue, that there currently isn't support for COM devices in Linux containers running on Windows.  And there's a WSL2 issue linked to that github issue about WSL2 not having USB support at all.
https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-expose-host-serial-port-to-container-correctly/81588/5

Comment: I've forgotten to say that I'm running everything on a Linux Raspbian.

Comment: Not sure if it could help, but I was just reading this post about adding Linux capabilities to a process in a container (`CAP_NET_ADMIN`, in that case), and I wonder if maybe you need to add `CAP_SYS_RAWIO`, `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` or `CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG`  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76580967/how-to-create-a-service-that-has-network-admin-privileges-through-the-docker-eng